# Algorithm to select what should be displayed on a map

Tags: algorithm, geometry, game-engine

In games, they only render the part of the scene that is visible on the screen.
For example, if an object is behind the player, it won't be rendered, or if it is too far it won't be rendered until it gets closer.

I would like to know what kind of algorithm/**datastructure** they use to determine whether or not they should display an object.

I need something that is very **fast**.

Comment: What kind of viewport do you have? A top-down viewport needs a different approach than a perspective view. It sounds like you're using a first-person perspective.

Comment: What kind of objects do you have on the scene? Can they be reasonably bounded by a cube or a box? I _guess_ your objects (sans terrain) are reasonably small.

Comment: It's a perspective view. And yes, the objects can be bounded by a cube. If the cubes are too big, they can be cut to get smaller cubes.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [**binary space partitioning**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) (BSP), which is a method for recursively subdividing a space into convex sets by hyperplanes. This subdivision gives rise to a representation of objects within the space by means of a tree data structure known as a **BSP tree**.

See also [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) and [Octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).

There're two other related topics around StackExchange:

- [When to use Binary Space Partitioning, Quadtree, Octree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99796/when-to-use-binary-space-partitioning-quadtree-octree)
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19883/how-does-a-bsp-tree-work-for-z-sorting